# Specifying Parameters For Where To Find Shared Folders ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have asked this but it was marked as a duplicate, I do now want to add more folders to where the viewengine looks I want to control where it looks by passing more parameters to the RenderPartial.

I have been trying to figure this out and have been struggling, is it possible to control the shared folders, we have a lot of areas in our application and some of the views in those areas are used in multiple places and the Shared folder under views is getting huge so would it be possible to create a way to do the following:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomeIdentifer", "ViewName"); %>
```

If we could do that we could have it look at the shared folder under the area "SomeIdentifier" or create a "SomeIdentifier" folder under the root views shared folder.

Is this possible?

For the record I don't want to add lots more folders to be searched as surely that will slow down the finding of a view and also there could be views with the same name. I want to tell the RenderPartial where to look, in this case look in a folder under shared called "SomeIdentifier".

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the full path to your view like:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SomeFolder/YetAnotherFolder/yourview.cshtml", "ViewName"); %>
```